# Thread safety in multithreaded access to LinkedList

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

My application needs to keep an access log of requests to a certain resource and multiple threads will be recording log entries.  The only pertinent piece of information is the timestamp of the request and the stats being retrieved will be how many requests occurred in the last X seconds.  The method that returns the stats for a given number of seconds also needs to support multiple threads.

I was thinking of approaching the concurrency handling using the [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-frame.html) framework, with which I am not the most familiar, hence this question.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ConcurrentRecordStats 
{
    private LinkedList<Long> recLog;
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public LinkedConcurrentStats()
    {
        this.recLog = new LinkedList<Long>();
    }

    //this method will be utilized by multiple clients concurrently
    public void addRecord(int wrkrID)
    {
        long crntTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.lock.lock();
        this.recLog.addFirst(crntTS);
        this.lock.unlock();
    }

    //this method will be utilized by multiple clients concurrently
    public int getTrailingStats(int lastSecs)
    {
        long endTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long bgnTS = endTS - (lastSecs * 1000);

        int rslt = 0;

        //acquire the lock only until we have read
        //the first (latest) element in the list
        this.lock.lock();

        for(long crntRec : this.recLog)
        {
            //release the lock upon fetching the first element in the list
            if(this.lock.isLocked()) 
            {
                this.lock.unlock();
            }

            if(crntRec > bgnTS)
            {
                rslt++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return rslt;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Will this use of `ReentrantLock` insure thread safety?
2. Is it needed to use a lock in `getTrailingStats`?
3. Can I do all this using `synchronized` blocks?  The reason I went with locks is because I wanted to have the same lock in both R and W sections so that both writes and reading of the first element in the list (most recently added entry) is done a single thread at a time and I couldn't do that with just `synchronized`.
4. Should I use the [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) instead?

Comment: Just to know, why aren't you simply using public `List<T> Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)` to obtain a thread safe list?

Comment: will this eliminate the need for locks?

Comment: Java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque is thread safe with a weakly consistent iterator.

Comment: what does `weakly consistent iterator` mean?

Comment: It is well explained in the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html#iterator()

Comment: so if i use `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`, i can get rid of the locks.  nice, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locks can present a major performance bottleneck.  An alternative is to use [a ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html): use `offerFirst` to add a new element, and use the (weakly consistent) `iterator` (that won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`) in place of your for-each loop.  The advantage is that this will perform much better than your implementation or than the `synchronizedList` implementation, but the disadvantage is that the iterator is weakly consistent - thread1 might add elements to the list while thread2 is iterating through it, which means that thread2 won't count those new elements.  However, this is functionally equivalent to having thread2 lock the list so that thread1 can't add to it - either way thread2 isn't counting the new elements.

Comment: if T2 adds an element while T1 is iterating through it that is not a problem because T1 is not counting the new elements

Comment: but also, my LinkedList won't trow a `ConcurrentModificationException` because I am iterating only through formerly entered elements

Comment: IOW, the lock in `getTrailingStats` takes care of not inserting new elements while the first existing element is being read

Comment: @amphibient The linked list's iterator isn't clever enough to know that you're using it in such a way that modifications to the list won't matter - it uses a counter of the number of modifications made to the list and the number of modifications made by the iterator, and if these counters don't match then it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, which may occur after you unlock the `lock` while still iterating through the list via the for-each loop. You would need to maintain the `lock` though the entire loop to avoid the exception.

Comment: I actually have a simulation of multiple threads writing while others are reading it doesn't cause the exception

Comment: IOW, once I fetch the first element, the further iterations go from there towards the end of the list and are unaffected by new insertions that are located BEFORE the first element of the loop

Comment: Why not use one of the standard concurrent collections?

Comment: @assylias Most of the standard concurrent collections are queues where you add to the tail and iterate from the head, but he needs a collection where you add to the head and iterate from the head. Though in hindsight I keep forgetting that Java7 added a ConcurrentLinkedDeque

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque allows head insertion and iteration.