# Correct usage of ConcurrentLinkedDeque

Tags: java

Hello as opposed to using `linkedlist with (reentrant lock)` or using `ArrayList (with Collections.synchronizedList)` I read that using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` would eliminate using read/writes locks. What I'm trying to do is add a game character object, this object will be added and removed every time a character enters a map (field) or leaves the map. We can have hundreds of players entering or leaving any map at a time...

This is what I have done

```
private final ConcurrentLinkedDeque<User> charUsers;

public Field() {
    this.charUsers = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
}

public User getUserByID(int id) {
    return charUsers.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null);
}

public void addUser(User chr) {
    if (!charUsers.contains(chr)) {
        charUsers.add(chr);
    }
    broadcastPacket(UserPool.userEnterField(chr), chr);
}

public void removeUser(User chr) {
    charUsers.remove(chr); // or charUsers.remove();?
    broadcastPacket(UserPool.userLeaveField(chr), chr);
}

public void broadcastPacket(byte[] outPacket, User exceptChr) {
    charUsers.stream().filter(chr -> !chr.equals(exceptChr)).forEach(
            chr -> chr.getClient().getSession().send(outPacket)
    );
}
```

I'm kinda worried about concurrency, and I've read that `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` is threadsafe in a multi-threaded environment but it's weakly consistent when using iterator. I am trying to avoid any `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`.

If that's not the case, would I be better off with a sync.List with `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`?

A side question related to this game design, I'm basing this of a fairly old java based game that used java 1.5 at the time I believe and they used `hashmaps` instead to add/remove entities/objects for the game (Characters, maps, mobs, npcs). There was some concurrency issues I believe even with usage of `ReentrantLock`. So i'm trying a different approach. (Although it there could be other factors to the issue, I believe this to be the main one).

Comment: *"I read that using ConcurrentLinkedDeque would eliminate using read/writes."* - Where did you read that?

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are asking here.  The only clear question I can see is whether you would be "better off" using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` or a synchronized list.  And that is basically unanswerable ... because it will depend on the *entire* design of your application AND the requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847935/thread-safety-in-multithreaded-access-to-linkedlist.

Comment: Basically this is for a multiplayer game i'm trying to emulate, every time a player enters a map (spawns in the map). The map will show other spawned object such as monsters, or npcs. I'm at the early stages of development where I haven't yet added the NPCs, Mobs yet. this is just the map aspect of when a player enters the map.

Comment: That doesn't help.  Basically this question is too broad.

Comment: Hmm, it's based on Netty non-blocking IO. Has a Game, Login server which interacts with the center server for cross inter-server communication. The client is also handled with netty. Client sends a response, server receives it and handles it accordingly. In this case client sends a response for spawning the player to a the map, and I have to handle it server-sided. When a player enters a map he can interact with other players, go to a different map, kill monsters in the map or talk to NPCs.

Comment: You are missing the point.  The problem is that the only way we could give you an objective answer to this is if >>we<< implemented the (entire) game and benchmarked it, and tested to see if the the `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` approach that you have in your head has problems.  (And of course, there is the minor problem of reading your mind ... :-) )

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying. Thank you for replying. I guess I just go with what I have and deal with issues once they arise then worry about them before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from the code you posted, it looks like what you're using `charUsers` for is just keeping track of everything that's in the current map. You're scanning through the collection to find entities, and you're adding and removing entities. And you're concerned about concurrent access to the collection? What about consistency, are you concerned about that? Like, thread A adds a thing, thread B removes it, and then thread A tries to act as though the thing is still in the collection; do you care? That's part of your concurrency problem.

Now, a linked list is great if what you want is a *list* and you're going to be adding and removing nodes all the time and not necessarily at the ends. But a linked list is terrible if you want to search a collection for a specific item and you mostly don't care about *all items* at the same time. Maybe you want a map, after all -- ConcurrentHashMap, where the key is the thing's ID and the value is the thing. Every time you search for a thing, you're going to have to traverse that list until you find it, which winds up being an O(N) problem, right, and while you're traversing that list you are exposed to concurrent modification (maybe you want a CopyOnWriteArrayList, if you've got RAM to burn).

I agree with the other commenter that this question is probably too broad to get a solid yes/no answer. There are lots of different approaches to minimizing the cost of synchronization and concurrent access, but they are all driven by the goals of the system. One approach may be great for one system but terrible for another.

I'd suggest doing something naive and workable and profiling it or in some other way measuring its performance against your desired outcome. That can let you see where you really need to optimize.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight. There are cases where I would need access to all the characters to send a message to, as well as just send something to a specific character hence the brodcastPacket code I posted. I guess I might be better off using HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap instead of ConcurrentLinkedDeque.

Comment: One thing to know about HashMap is that it is specifically *not* thread-safe. The way the implementation works, if you've got a writer thread adding an element to a bucket and you've got a reader thread looking in that same bucket for an element that isn't there then you can get that reader thread stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah I'll need to use ReentrantReadWriteLock here if I go with HashMap to manage my own threads. But i'm wondering If I use an ArrayList instead, I can just add `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());` to the character object. Which I think should be thread-safe? Thanks~

Comment: Yep, it will be synchronized.